# Measuring a single-qubit PauliZ using Qiskit's EstimatorQNN

Tags: qiskit, pauli-gates, quantum-neural-network, logical-observables

I am currently working with the `EstimatorQNN` from Qiskit to construct a Quantum Neural Network using a custom Parametrized Quantum Circuit. But I want to change the observables in the `EstimatorQNN`.

By default, the observable returns the product of Pauli Z operators across all qubits in the parametrized quantum circuit. However, I am interested in having the observable return the Pauli Z operator for each qubit individually.

Could you provide guidance on how to modify the observable parameter to achieve this specific behavior?